# Drag event firing but click event not firing on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I have a calendar application where users can click items, which generates a popup allowing the user to amend the details, or drag items to move them to a different day.

On mobiles, I use [touchpunch](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch) to allow this dragging to happen. It works fine on iPhones, but on Android the draggable stuff appears to get fired at the expense of the click.

The following code illustrates the problem. On iPhone, if you click the `div` it triggers the click event. If you drag the `div` it triggers the drag events and then the click event, which is fine. On Android, if you click the `div` it triggers the drag events.

Is this a limitation or bug in touchpunch, or a configuration I am missing, or something else? Thank you for reading!

```js
$("#myel").click(function() {
  alert("Clicked");
});

$("#myel").draggable({
  stop: function() {
    alert("Dragged");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<div id="myel" style="border:solid 1px black;padding:8px;width:120px;">
  Click me or drag me
</div>
```

Comment: I would assume it's a bug in the library on modern devices, given that it hasn't been updated in 9.5 years - https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch. I'd suggest finding a more up to date library to fill your requirement.

Comment: Is there one you'd recommend?